# Bootstrap 4, scss @import generates a different file than the original on getbootstrap.com

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm using `node-sass` for my project.

You can try in a simple *style.scss* file with both version (alpha6 and beta):

```
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

then type this:

```
node-sass style.scss style.css
```

and you'll have a different css for the .btn class:

**- original one on getbootstrap.com (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css)**

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

**- generated one**

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Look at this:

```
transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
```

Why this differences?

**With this problem "disabled" property on a button has no transition anymore** as you can see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/LSeKKSaB2Lk2JMtoFi9K?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In short, your build process (based on your description) includes only a part of what Bootstrap does with their .sass files before they are released.

Bootstrap, in addition to just compiling Sass to CSS, also uses tools like Autoprefixer to fix the most common cross-vendor CSS issues by, for example, adding vendor prefixes to some properties (vide `user-select` in your `.btn`). You simply missed that step, hence your result file looks a bit different.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/build-tools/#tooling-setup

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm using that import because I need to override some variables (for example: $enable-rounded: false; -shadows: true;). How to do so?

Comment: It's not about the import, you probably don't have Autoprefixer set up.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Bootstrap, in their build process, uses Autoprefixer, a postcss plugin, to do some automated improvements on the compiled Sass code.

You don't include Autoprefixer in your build process, so your final Bootstrap package looks different.

Read the website I have linked in the answer and you'll have an idea of what's wrong.

Comment: OK thanks. But my question so about different properties value from the CSS online and mine. Except from autoprefixer which now I know. Look at the transition prop.